# convert sql statment to linq MVC

Tags: linq

How can I convert the following `SQL` statement to `linQ`?

```
select * from student where student_id in (4 , 10 , 20 , 50)
```

I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
var SelectedStudent = db.Students
            .Include(i => i.grade)
            .Where(i => i.studentID  in  (1,2,3))
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ids = new [] { 1,2,3};

var students =
    from student in db.Students
    where ids.Contains (student.StudentId)
    select student;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var collIds={10,20,30,40};

var results=(from s in dbo.Student
        join c in collIds
        on s.id equals c
        select s).ToList();
```